# How to search a CSV file using a key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, papaparse

I want to create a function in JavaScript that searches a CSV file using a someones name and then outputs the corresponding email address

**CSV File Format:**

```
 Name:               Email:
exampleName      example@example.com
exampleName2     example2@example.com
exampleName3     example3@example.com
```

I think I might be able to use PapaParse as the file will be stored online in a remote directory (not a local file).

**Example Of PapaParse**
https://www.papaparse.com/

```
    // Parse CSV string
var data = Papa.parse(csv);

// Convert back to CSV
var csv = Papa.unparse(data);

// Parse local CSV file
Papa.parse(file, {
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log("Finished:", results.data);
    }
});

// Stream big file in worker thread
Papa.parse(bigFile, {
    worker: true,
    step: function(results) {
        console.log("Row:", results.data);
    }
});
```

If someone could help me create this function it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: use https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.8.9/jquery.csv.js

Comment: @UllasHunka That doesn't really answer my question

Comment: That was not an answer  but a suggestion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file this is an example of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const csv = "Name,Email\nexampleName,example@example.com\nexampleName2,example2@example.com"
const csvData = Papa.parse(csv, {header:true}).data

function findEmailByName(name) {
  return csvData.filter(data => data.Name === name)[0].Email
}

console.log(
  findEmailByName('exampleName2')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.5.0/papaparse.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: How would you do it with a remote server? Tried replacing string with web address in the following format 'example.com' however it cannot find the resource.

Comment: Here's an example using a remote server: https://codepen.io/rustydev/pen/GBKGKG?editors=0010

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much!